# OS 10.10.3 Wifi issue

Tags: macos, wifi, osx-yosemite

since a few days the wifi connection is dropping after about 2min. I have to deactivate and activate the wifi, then everything is working fine for a couple of minutes. All other devices are fin, but on other networks (office) I have the same problem. I tried everything from: [Techrepublic.com](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-how-to-troubleshoot-wi-fi-issues-in-os-x-yosemite/)  or [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6995894?tstart=0) but I still have the same problem. No Problem if I use cable. Maybe after 200pings to the router the wifi is gone.

I didn't install any thing the last few days and I'm on OSX 10.10.3 for a few months. I hope someone can help.

OSX 10.10.3 - MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking your computer to a certified Apple Repair shop as it sound like your AirPort Card (Wireless Card) is broken.

If not then try booting in to recovery mode and testing the web browser within there (whilst connected to wifi). If this works then you can confirm it is a Software issue (Problem with our install of OSX) and if not then it most likely safe to say you should take it in for a repair / checkup.

To boot in to recovery mode;

1. Turn off the computer
2. Start the computer whilst holding down [COMMAND + R]
3. Keep holding until you see an Apple Logo appear
4. Wait for it to load then connect to Wireless Router (Top right)
5. Now try the internet browser
6. To exit this just turn off the computer and start it as normal

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't do anything, but now it works again since two days. Don't know why, but thank you!